# How to make my SQLite database be saved and accessed from different devices

Tags: android, sqlite, save

I am making a login and registration forms with SQLite database. I want to save my data and be able to access it from different devices, but it happens that the data is saved on the device Im currently using and when I cahnge the emulator the database is empty and I have to insert new values to it(which is not the case here for the login/registation form). How can I make it to be able to save data, inserted from different devices, and then access it from everywhere.
I'm sorry if I didn't describe my question very well, but I hope you understood it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You must use a web service, serving the data from a remore database.

Comment: You need a remote database that is online using webservices. SQLite database is limited to just a single device and it is not wise to use a handset as a database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a remote Database. Web API to access the DB. Local DB wont help you with the problem you specified.

[Please Check this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

in addition to comments, you can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)..

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a server in between. you gotta make a webservice then send the registration data to the webservice then the webservice saves the data on the SERVER database (not your device database). then whenever you ant to login you call the webserivce login method. it checks your data and says you can login or not.

the DB on your mobile device is just for saving data that you need to use locally.